# Messages appearing on locked screen

Tags: ios, messages, notifications

How can I hide text messages from the locked screen of my iPhone 4S?
I find that having a password is useless as everyone could read messages from the locked screen.

Answer (score 5):

- On the iPhone select Preferences -> Notifications -> Messages
- Scroll to the bottom
- Turn off "View on Lock Screen"

You have to repeat this for all notifications you don't want to be shown on the lock screen.